# User profile does not show the link to careers

Tags: support

I looked over the new user profile layout today and one thing that caught my attention was at the end of the *Edit Profile & Settings* tab. There you find a box that *should* link to your SO careers profile which it does not for me

> [image]

When I click on the link to the right, then I'm instantly taken to my profile ([the public version is here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/halirutan)).

How is this supposed to work?